# Mysql can't lock tables when using prepared statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Trying to run a prepared insert statement after locking the table for write give me this error for mysql : This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet : LOCK TABLES tbl WRITE.

Any workaround for this issue ? Engine using for the table  : INNODB .

P.S. : I wanted to lock the tables so i could avoid duplicate inserts (making the duplicate check on the application side not db side , unique index is out of question for varchar(5000)) . So i would need to lock the tables , but i can't do this with prepared statements . Will I get same error for stored procedures ? Any other ideeas regarding this issue ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by locking the table?

Comment: @N.B. I am trying to avoid duplicate inserts . I can't use UNIQUE index because the column is varchar(5000)

Comment: I'd create another column that'd serve as unique index and I'd put a hash of your varchar data in there, like md5(your_varchar_col) or sha1 / whichever you deem fit. You avoid all the problems of having table locks and what not.

Comment: @n.b. md5 is not unique . Not even sha1

Comment: Use the proper way to lock in InnoDB - `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: There are 2^128 possible hash values for MD5. It's highly unlikely that you'll use a single percent of that number during your lifetime. MD5 is a fast algorithm, but you're free to use any other hashing algorithm. Point being, you can use unique indexes if you are smart about it. Or you can lock the tables and have great fun with unreleased locks, stored procedures and similar nice things while trying to have a unique varchar(5000) (why 5000 is beyond me, simply use text type there).

Comment: I have a unique sequential char string attached to some urls . This is for url shortner . The db could fill very fast with urls (urls which might contain yes 5000 bytes for alot of get data) . Good point about hashing but i would have prefered some write locks . I will take into consideration

Comment: @vatev i need write lock not read lock

Comment: I'm sorry for trying to sound overly aggressive here, but to me it seems the approach is wrong. You'd basically use write locks for supposedly high traffic database, used for URL shortener. Why wouldn't you allow duplicates? Trust me that locks are one of the worst demons you can encounter, especially when they don't get released and you have several hundred or thousand writes queued. Judging by what you said, you can get away by using a hash to prevent dupes or you can simply allow them.

Comment: Don't use prepared statements for this query ! just execute this lock query. Why using prepared statements for simple queries like this anyway, I use them only for queries that has variables with unknown values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transactions, create a hash column, and put a unique key on that column.

As Geo C. said in his comments, you will almost certainly never have a collision using MD5, and you're even less likely to do so with SHA256.  No matter how many URLs you generate, even billions of them would be nothing compared to the number of hashes you can generate before the odds of a collision are high enough to think about a complicated workaround using locks.

Comment: Sometimes you can't avoid a table-lock if you want to completely avoid deadlock. If you want to perform UPDATEs and DELETEs on a table as well as INSERTs (in that order), you may end up with deadlock when one transaction has a lock on a table-index and another one has a lock on the PK index and they are waiting on each other. Re-ordering writes is not always possible. Re-tries are an acceptable technique for recovery depending upon the use-case, but avoiding them with a table-lock is cleaner.

Comment: These days where clusters are becoming more common, table-locks are becoming less and less meaningful since you can't lock a table across a cluster. So table-locks are something that can't really protect you from having to implement re-try logic on all your writes, just in case the commit can't be replicated across the cluster. So while table-locks may seem to be the "right choice", they may be useless in the long-run.